# The transcendence of sine function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials

Are there polynomials $$R_2(x) ,R_1(x),R_0(x)$$ $$R_2(x)\text{ not the zero polynomial} $$ such  as  $$R_2(x)\sin^2(x) +R_1(x)\sin(x)+R_0(x)=0\quad \forall x\in[a,b]?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that we are dealing with analytic functions here. Therefore, by the identity theorem, if the equality$$R_2(x)\sin^2(x)+R_1(x)\sin(x)+R_0(x)=0$$holds on $[a,b]$, it holds for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

So, the answer is negative, because then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}):R_0(n\pi)=-R_2(n\pi)\sin^2(n\pi)-R_1(n\pi)\sin(n\pi)=0,$$Since a non-zero polynomial cannot have infinitely many zeros, $R_0(x)\equiv0$. So, we have$$R_2(x)\sin^2(x)-R_1(x)\sin(x)=0,$$and this implies that $R_2(x)\sin(x)+R_1(x)=0$. By the same argument as above, $R_1(x)\equiv0$. So, $R_2(x)\sin(x)=0$ and this implies that $R_2(x)\equiv0$, which goes against our assumptions.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I have edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Using the fact they're entire functions was also my idea. +1

Comment: Nice one with entire functions, +1

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Note that I believe that there must be a not too complicated way of solving the problem without using this approach.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I believe it, too, but I can't find it right now

Comment: @TZakrevskiy (and Santos): For a "not too complicated way", perhaps you're thinking of something along the lines of [A. N. Niel's 18 July 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4928211). Also, [This 18 March 2006 sci.math post of mine](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4552770) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let
$$f(x):=p\cos t+q\sin t+r=0$$ where $p,q,r$ are polynomials.

Differentiating twice and adding the initial equation,

$$f''(t)+f(t)=p''\cos t-2p'\sin t+q''\sin t+2q'\cos t+r+r''=0.$$

In this expression, the degrees of the factors of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ have decreased by one. We can iterate and in the end we will obtain an expression of the form

$$a\cos t+b\sin t+s=0$$ where at least one of $a,b$ is a nonzero constant. Then by further differentiations,

$$c\cos t+d\sin t=0,$$ which is not possible.

I am fairly confident that this generalizes to quadratic expressions in $\cos t$ and $\sin t$.

---

**Solution:**

If you apply the differential operator $(D^4+5D^2+4)$ to an expression of the form

$$p\cos(2t)+q\sin(2t)+r\cos(t)+s\sin(t)+u$$ where at least one of $p,q,r,s$ is a non-constant polynomial, you get an expression of the same form, where the largest polynomial degree is lower.

(For instance, $x^4\cos(2x)\to48x^3\sin(2x)-228x^2\cos(2x)-192x\sin(2x)+24\cos(2x)$. It can be proven formally for any monomial, then polynomial, but the computation is a little tedious.)

By iterating, you eventually obtain a non-trivial linear combination of
$$\cos(2t),\sin(2t),\cos(t),\sin(t),$$

which cannot be identically zero.

Comment: If we replace $\sin^2x$ with $\frac {1-\cos 2x}{2} $ and then try to apply this method directly, the extra factor  $4$ in $-4p(x) \cos 2x$ (and the absence of this factor in $-q(x)\sin x $) will not allow us to go further.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: doesn't $g(t):=f''(t)+f(t)$ then $h(t):=g''(t)+4g(t)$ deal with that ?

Comment: We can try something easier: $g=f'+f$, this will give us a combination of $\sin 2x$, $\cos 2x$,  $\sin x$, and $\cos x$ with polynomial coefficients. After that, by a sufficient number of maps $h\to h''+4h$ we can reduce this expression to a combination of just $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, and then apply your method. There will be some points where we would need to prove that along all those differentiations we don't loose some information, but that seems easy.

Comment: Sorry guys... I have just noticed that I can vote your nice answers!

Comment: @dmtri: you are also deemed to *accept* (√ sign) the answer that suits you (if any).